# Lista de objetos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo uma função que retorna uma lista de objeto. Trecho do código:

```
def guarda_word(lista_palavras,lista_objeto,indice):

    for i in lista_palavras:
        if bool(lista_objeto) == True: # a list de objeto esta vazia
            i = PalavraIndices(i)
            i.add_item(indice,1)
            lista_objeto.append(i)
        elif i not in lista_objeto: # o elemento da lista de palavras ainda nao tem um objeto
            i = PalavraIndices(i)
            i.add_item(indice,1)
            lista_objeto.append(i)
        else:
            i.add_item(indice,1)
    return lista_objeto

lista_objeto = guarda_word(palavras_A,lista_objeto,'arquivoA')

print(lista_objeto)
```

O problema é, quando printo essa lista de objeto na tela.. ela sai desse jeito:

```
[<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6970>, <__main__.PalavraIndices 
object at 0x005E6990>, <__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E69B0>, 
<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E69D0>, <__main__.PalavraIndices 
object at 0x005E69F0>, <__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6A30>, 
<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6A50>, <__main__.PalavraIndices 
object at 0x005E6A70>, <__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6A90>, 
<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6A10>, <__main__.PalavraIndices 
object at 0x005E6AB0>, <__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6AD0>, 
<__main__.PalavraIndices object at 0x005E6AF0>]
```

Alguém sabe o proque não está apenas aparecendo o nome de cada objeto nessa lista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve adicionar um método `__repr__(self)` no objeto instanciado, que irá retornar uma string como você quer que ela seja exibida em tela.

Veja [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675771/object-to-string-in-python) resposta para mais informações.

```
def __repr__(self):
     return str(self.__dict__)
```

Comment: show mano! funcionou certinho! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Se o objetivo for apenas mostrar só o nome da class, podes fazer assim:

```
class Foo:
    pass
print(Foo().__class__.__name__) # Foo
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MQJg/1)

Mas se quiseres uma coisa mais personalizada para cada objeto (instância da classe) consoante as entradas podes fazer por exemplo:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Class {} em que na sua variável de instância bar é {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.bar)

print(Foo('hey')) # Class Foo em que na sua variável de instância bar é hey
print(Foo('lol')) # Class Foo em que na sua variável de instância bar é lol
print(Foo('bar')) # Class Foo em que na sua variável de instância bar é bar
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MQJg/2)

Mas se não declarares este método, ou neste caso `__str__(self)`, o output para isso é apenas esse 'descritivo geral'.

Existem alguns exemplos de classes que se usam com muita frequência que funcionam exatamente assim:

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal('10.5')) # 10.5
print(Decimal('21.2')) # 21.2
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/MQJg)

Comment: eu criei o ` def __repr__(self):`, na minha classe.. e deu certo... está retornando o nome de cada objeto instanciado, na lista de objetos